# Declarar variável dentro do meu cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho esse código em meu arquivo cshtml

```
<div class="grid_19 box-resultado">
@{
    string
        nm, dia, mes, ano, sexo, numpassaporte,
        diavalidade, mesvalidade,
        anovalidade, paisemissao, dados = "";
.......
```

Preciso declarar uma variável `int`, cujo valor vem de um campo no formulário. Esse é o campo em meu formulário.

```
<div class="grid_5">
    <input id="txtTesteQdePass"
           type="text"
           name="txtTesteQdePass"
           class="grid_4  required"
           placeholder="Entre com a qde de passageiros" />
</div>
```

Como eu faço para passar o valor do edit `txtTesteQdePass` para essa variável?

Comment: Faltou essas linhas na pergunta.                               <div class="grid_5">
                                    <input id="txtTesteQdePass" type="text" name="txtTesteQdePass" class="grid_4  required" placeholder="Entre com a qde de passageiros" />
                                </div>

Comment: Não faltou... é porque você tem que formatar melhor a pergunta antes de enviar. Dá pra visualizar o resultado do que será enviado antes de enviar.

Comment: @pnet você queria que o valor do campo fosse passado no tempo de execução para o método q você criou no cshtml @{ string nm .... } É isso?

Answer (score 1):

Não faz sentido alimentar uma variável server side em tempo de execução sem executar um postback. Aliás, isso nem é permitido, você teria que executar sua parte server side para conseguir. A melhor forma seria implementar método em seu controller recebendo o valor do input, armazenando o valor da variável em uma `ViewBag` e depois fazendo o uso desejado:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Metodo(int txtTesteQdePass)
{
    ViewBag.txtTesteQdePass = txtTesteQdePass;

    return View("nomedaview");
}
```

Em seguida, na sua view, você terá o valor armazenado em `@ViewBag.txtTesteQdePass`

Answer (score 1):

Não é bem assim que sistemas web funcionam.

A caixa de texto é algo que vai aparecer para o cliente preencher e depois submeter para o servidor... ai sim você terá a oportunidade de recolher os valores que forem submetidos.

No ASP.NET MVC, você pode pegar os valores em um método chamado de `action`, que fica dentro de uma classe chamada de `Controller`. Esse método pode receber os valores submetidos pelo cliente por uma símples correspondência de nome dos parâmetros com os IDs dos `input`s, `select`s e `textarea`s que estiverem dentro do form submetido.

Answer (score 0):

Quem vai fazer esse controle de dados é a sua controller. Caso você deseje passar esse valor para ela basta colocar o atributo name do seu input com o nome da variável que será recebida no seu backend.

View:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Recebe">
     <input type="text" name="quantidade"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Controler:

```
public ActionResult(int quantidade)
{
      View(quantidade);
}
```